# dotnet restore works locally but fails when building Docker container

Tags: docker, .net-core, windows-10

If I create a new console application using `dotnet classlib -lang f# -o hello-docker`, `cd` into the directory and then run `dotnet restore`, everything works as expected.

However, if I add a `Dockerfile` with the following content

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2-sdk

WORKDIR /hello

COPY hello-docker.fsproj .
COPY *.fs ./

RUN dotnet restore

RUN dotnet build

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "run" ]
```

and run `docker build .`, it fails to reach `nuget.org` with the following message:

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/NuGet.targets(102,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [/hello/hello-docker.fsproj]
>   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/NuGet.targets(102,5): error :   An error occurred while sending the request. [/hello/hello-docker.fsproj]
>   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/NuGet.targets(102,5): error :   Couldn't resolve host name [/hello/hello-docker.fsproj]
>   The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore' returned a non-zero code: 1

Why can I restore locally, but not inside the Docker container?

Comment: You are using which OS?

Comment: @tarunlalwani Windows 10.

Comment: I think for some reason internet is not working in your Docker containers. Try restarting the docker VM from settings

Comment: @tarunlalwani Yes, I tried that but without success. I've also rebooted the entire machine without the problem going away.

Comment: I don't see anything specific on the MobyVM which does that kind of connection sharing. Open HyperV manager and in the mobyvm try adding a additional NAT network manually and see if it helps

Comment: @TarunLalwani I managed to test this on a different computer now, and here it works, which I guess means that there's something fishy with the config on the laptop where it fails. I'll try again tonight and see if I can dig deeper into the config of that machine, but what am I looking for?

Comment: Honestly not sure, try getting rid of docker and reinstalling it and see if it is of any help

Comment: Yeah, reinstalling docker did the trick. Weird, but I guess there was some firewall rule somewhere that borked it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad, its solved for you :-). Sometimes first time installation are not perfect. I have seen it in few other places also.

Comment: Did you try to use the `--network host` flag, e.g. `docker build --network host`?

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it by going into properties/sharing on my network adapter and shared it with the hyper-v/docker switch...think it was called nat or something.

Comment: Can you elaborate the steps you followed

Comment: for me (on windows 10), i right clicked the wifi icon at the bottom right, click "Open network & Internet Settings" then click "Change adapter options", then right click the current adapter I was using for internet (wifi in my case), click properties, go to sharing tab, click "allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connection" then from the dropdown i picked vEthernet (DockerNAT) or whatever is equivalent for your machine